# Not able to connect azure devops on prem from visual studio 2019 in manage connections with 400 bad request error

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am not able to connect Azure Devops on prem version from visual studio 2019 using manage connections tab. I have received 400 bad request error, I have tried with and without defaultcollection in the end but the response remains the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the hostname instead of the ip address to check if it works.

And try to configure the "~\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" file, set the sites binding:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="ip address:port:host header" />
```

For more information, you could refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding#configuration-sample

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps: Git->Clone Repository
Chose the Path where you want to storage the Repo and click on "Browse a Repository"->Azure Devops

This works to me, i hope this could be usefull :)